# DirectX 11 and g++ compile error

Tags: c++, g++, directx-11

Hello I actually learning DirectX 11 with this tutorial: http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut03.html

**First Part**

My code (where the probleme come from): 
d3dclass.h:

```
//Linking
#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dx11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dx10.lib")

//Include
#include <dxgi.h>
#include <d3dcommon.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx10math.h>
```

I do all like the tutorial, the only diference is I compile it with g++, trough this the command :

g++ -mwindows WinMain.cpp systemclass.cpp inputclass.cpp graphicsclass.cpp d3dclass.cpp -o Prog.exe -I "D:\Programme File\DirectX SDK\Include" 2> log.txt

but in the output file, I have a large sum of errors. This is the log.txt:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XUlcAFUyRcLIvdKbe0FkLVjkvwxpOmEv

To sum up the log there is a lot of things like __in which has not been declared in the dxgi.h, but this header is from DirectX11 Library;

**Second Part**

I found the way to fix a lot of my problem (of the first part) with adding this :

```
#define __in
#define __out
#define __inout
#define __in_bcount(x)
#define __out_bcount(x)
#define __in_ecount(x)
#define __out_ecount(x)
#define __in_ecount_opt(x)
#define __out_ecount_opt(x)
#define __in_bcount_opt(x)
#define __out_bcount_opt(x)
#define __in_opt
#define __inout_opt
#define __out_opt
#define __out_ecount_part_opt(x,y)
#define __deref_out
#define __deref_out_opt
#define __RPC__deref_out
```

but there still is a major problem, this is the error output :

```
 D:\Programme File\DirectX SDK\Include/d3dx10core.h:345:13: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
     HRESULT WINAPI_INLINE GetDesc(D3DX10_FONT_DESCA *pDesc) { return GetDescA(pDesc); }
```

it comes from WINAPI_INLINE (this is in the DirectX header)

How can I fix this? please.

Comment: Please try to narrow it down and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. Don't link to code, post the code.

Comment: I can't post the log.text it makes 120,000 characters, the site won't let me publish it. But the problem comes from the includes (I test it and the error log is the same) : 

//Include
#include <dxgi.h>
#include <d3dcommon.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx10math.h>

Comment: @Carl You don't need to do this, no one is going to read 120,000 characters anyway.

Comment: I've update my previous comment

Comment: to sum up the error there is a lot of things like __in which are undefined in the dxgi.h the problem is this is the DirectX File not mine

Comment: I hope my edit is enough homogeneous and understandable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have any experience with using g++, but I can help with a few details here. To use g++ you need to [install the Windows SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/sdk-archive) and configure it to include the proper paths. The legacy DirectX SDK requires the Windows SDK and is not fully standalone.

> Note that the legacy DirectX SDK and the Windows SDK don't claim to be compatible with the GCC toolchain.

The `__in`, `__out`,  etc. macros are called "SAL annotations" and they are there to improve the quality of static code analysis both internally at Microsoft and when using Visual C++'s `/analyze` switch. They are defined as 'blank' in other cases so they just get removed from the code. The macros are defined in the Windows SDK. You can try explicitly doing a `#include <sal.h>` and/or `#include <specstrings.h>` before including a version of `dxgi.h`.

Another thing to keep in mind is that the legacy DirectX SDK itself is [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx) along with the `D3DX9`, `D3DX10`, and `D3DX1` utility libraries. As such, if you are using the Windows 8.0, 8.1, or 10 SDK you can code Direct3D 11 without using it at all--see [Living without D3DX](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/). If you do want to continue to use those older helpers--which the somewhat dated rastertek tutorials assume--, you can do so but you need to make sure the DirectX SDK include and lib paths are searched *after* the Windows SDK include/lib paths.

> If you were using Visual C++ (which BTW has a [free Community edition](https://aka.ms/vs2017cpp) available), then you'd probably be having an easier time. You might also want to see the [DirectX Tool Kit tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki).

Comment: I will test it tomorrow. But I would know if you know a good site or PDF or Book (even if I need to by it) which is very complete (like the rastertek tutorial) and less obsolete and maybe on the DirectX12 (I found this but I don't know if it is good: https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Programming-DirectX-Computer-Science/dp/1942270062 )

Comment: See [this post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2014/04/07/book-recommendations/) and [this one](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2016/09/15/getting-started-with-direct3d-12/)

Comment: Hi, I've now another problem I don't know where I can find this: vcruntime.h. In my output log, I have this error:  error: vcruntime.h: No such file or directory. (just for information, I use g++ because I can compile a c++ code through another program but if you know the way to compile a Visual Studio Project File trough another program tell me)

Comment: I found vcruntime.h, it doesn't work too, that's totally annoying me. I bought the directX11 book and will use visual studio. Do you know to compile a Visual Studio Project trough another program (maybe I should open a new Question). Thanks for your help.